# Degree 6 covering space of a wedge of two circles whose group of deck transformations is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Using Caley graphs with two different sets of generators, I was able to obtain two non-isomorphic, degree 6, connected covering spaces of the wedge of two circles whose group of deck transformations was isomorphic to $S_3$.

I was wondering if it would be possible to find a third such covering space? What about a forth?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Remember that isomorphisms of covering space preserve which circle is which, so a covering space where one loop corresponds to an order-$3$ generator and the other an order-$2$ generator gives you two distinct covering spaces.  There are presentations where both generators are order-$3$, so I'm counting at least three non-isomorphic covering spaces.  Suggestion: classify presentations of $S_3$ having two generators, and consider the possible orders of generators.

Comment: @KyleMiller We have $S_3 = \{1, (12), (13), (23), (123), (132) \}$, so the only elements of order 3 are $(123)$ and $(132)$. But they generate the subgroup $\{ 1, (123), (132)\}$ and not $S_3$. What am I missing? Thanks :-)

Comment: I meant both order $2$